# Sequelize many-to-many error: is not a function

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship using sequelize, but everytime i try to use this function:
`member.addRole(role)`

I get this error:
`TypeError: member.addRole is not a function`

---

```
MemberRole = database.define('memberrole', {
    member_code: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    role_code: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
}, {
    timestamps:false
}

);
member.belongsToMany(role, { through: MemberRole, as: "role", foreignKey: "member_code" });
role.belongsToMany(member, { through: MemberRole, as: "member", foreignKey: "role_code" });

church.hasMany(member, { as: "member", foreignKey: "church_code" });
member.belongsTo(church, { as: "church", foreignKey: "church_code" });
```

---

```
const Roles = require('../models/roles');
const connection = require("../database/connection");
const Member = require('../models/member');
const { where } = require('sequelize');
require("../database/associations")


const memberRole = (req, res) => {
    
    connection.sync().then(() => {
        Member.update({
            member_name: "Nuevo",
            member_lastname: "Nuevo",
            member_birth: 2001 - 11 - 11,
            member_mail: "Nuevo@gmail.com",
            member_password: "Nuedecwfvo",
            member_image: "Nuevo",
            church_code: 1
        }, {
            where: {
                member_code: 1
            }
        }).then((member) => {
            Roles.update({
                role_name: "Nuevo",
                role_description: "Nuevadescriptio"
            }, {
                where: {
                    role_code: 1
                }
            }).then((role) => {
                member.addRole(role)
            })
        });

    });



module.exports = {
    getAllRoles,
    //getRoleMembers,
    memberRole
}
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: what is addRole function. Where have you defined it?

Comment: It is because `Model.update` returns array of numbers; how many rows affected (and which rows if you are using Postgres).  (https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-update) and don't return model instance. 

@ShaileshB it is called mixins which is added by Sequelize when you define associations. (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#special-methodsmixins-added-to-instances)